# Javascript: Inserting table rows for each element of an array, if array element populated

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array where not all elements will be populated. I want to output the contents of that array into an HTML table. I currently have this:

```
for (var basketRowJuice = 0; basketRowJuice < 10; basketRowJuice++){
    var outputName = "";
    outputName = (basketArray[0][basketRowJuice]);
    document.getElementById("basketJuiceName" + basketRowJuice).innerHTML = outputName;
}

for (var basketRowQuant = 0; basketRowQuant < 10; basketRowQuant++){
    var outputQuant = 0;
    outputQuant = (basketArray[1][basketRowQuant]);
    document.getElementById("basketJuiceQuant" + basketRowQuant).innerHTML = outputQuant;
}

for (var basketRowPrice = 0; basketRowPrice < 10; basketRowPrice++){
    var outputPrice = 0;
    outputPrice = (basketArray[2][basketRowPrice]);
    document.getElementById("basketJuicePrice" + basketRowPrice).innerHTML = outputPrice;
}
```

HTML table:

```
<table id="basket" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="This table lists the items you have in your shopping basket">
                                <caption>Your basket</caption>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Juice name</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Number of crates</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Total price</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName0"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant0"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice0"></td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName1"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant1"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice1"></td>
                                </tr>   
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName2"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant2"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName3"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant3"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice3"></td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName4"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant4"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice4"></td>
                                </tr>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName5"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant5"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice5"></td>
                                </tr>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName6"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant6"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice6"></td>
                                </tr>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName7"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant7"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice7"></td>
                                </tr>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName8"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant8"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice8"></td>
                                </tr>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceName9"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuiceQuant9"></td>
                                    <td id="basketJuicePrice9"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

However if my array is only populated in columns [0][9], [1][9] and [2][9] then i end up with a huge gap of empty rows in my HTML, before the output. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this? Perhaps so that my javascript inserts a table row for each populated array element?

I'm a newbie to programming so please excuse my no-doubt verbose and inelegant code.

Thank you,
Jon

Comment: That's weird format. Can you post your exact html please?

Comment: I tried to paste my html code but it wouldn't display!

Comment: Paste it, then select it and press Ctrl + K.

Comment: Do your arrays have 'undefined' where there is no data or some other content? (null, 0 (zero) ). If you have 'no data' to display for first row, I believe you don't want it at all, right? And third question: is it possible to have for a row values in just one array? (that is only one or two from name, price or quantity?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something more like the following inside your loops.

```
var outputPrice = basketArray[2][basketRowPrice];
if (outputPrice) {
    // do something here.  the if statement will be true for non-null, non-empty, non-zero values of the var outputPrice.
}
```

I'll also note that you can replace your 3 loops by one like:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var outputName = basketArray[i][j];
        var outputQuant = basketArray[1][basketRowQuant];
        //.. do the rest of the code
    }
}
```

The final step would be to remove the hard coded HTML and generate it dynamically, the following is without checking, so it probably is off a bit, look up the DOM methods.

```
var tbody = document.getElementById('basket').tbodies[0];
for (var j = 0; ...) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    for (var i = 0; ..) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = ...;
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
```